# Need help with questions about modeling and regression

Tags: regression, python, modeling

I have two questions that I am struggling with. It's not coding questions but more like theory questions.

### Fill in the blanks

> ________(1) has an output that is dependent on initialization, whereas ________ (2) has an output that is independent (or unaffected) by initialization.

Pick the combination for (1) and (2) amongst the four possibilities:

- **A.** (1) K-means; (2) Principle Components Analysis
- **B.** (1) Principle Components Analysis; (2) K-means
- **C.** (1) Y-Aware Principle Components Analysis; (2) Principle Components Analysis
- **D.** (1) Principle Components Analysis; (2) Y-Aware Principle Components Analysis

### Feature selection

Which of the following methods is most appropriate to select only relevant input features for a model?

- **A.** Ridge
- **B.** Lasso
- **C.** Elastic Net
- **D.** Logistics

For question 1, I have no clue which one is the answer but for question 2, I think all of those methods are correct. It will be great if anyone here can hele me with those questions.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure if I'm the only one struggling, but your post is really difficult to read, please consider clearly listing possible answers for 1) & 2) in question 1.

Comment: I just edited the question, Thank you!